# Use single event on more than one actor in libgdx

Tags: libgdx

I have two objects of `Actor` both of them having their different input listener having almost same position on stage. My question is how to detect touch on both of them using single InputEvent.

Answer (score 0):

Are their positions overlapping and you would actually touch both with your single input?

If you touch both, you can set the return value of the input listener of the upper (higher on the stage / touched first) Actor to false, so the input doesn't count as processed yet and gets passed through to the lower Actor.

Comment: both actors having same position and topmost actor detects touch and then event ends. solution which you have given is not working